# A question about \ifcat in the TeXbook

Tags: conditionals, primitives

In Chapter 20 of the TeXbook, Donald Knuth introduced the usage of `\ifcat` and he gave an example:

> For example, after
> `` \catcode`[=13 \catcode`]=13 \def[{*} ``
> the tests `\ifcat\noexpand[\noexpand]` and `\ifcat[*` will be true, but the test `\ifcat\noexpand[*` will be false.

I test the above example on my machine (mac, texlive2022) and have two queations:

1. There is `! Undefined control sequence.` error. (Edit: due to my typo, I'm sorry for that.)
2. There should be a control sequence following `\def`, so why can we write `\def[{*}` here?
3. Can you explain the difference between `\ifcat[*` and `\ifcat\noexpand[*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking for “active” in the TeXbook reveals (among others)

> (Page 40) **Exercise 7.5** Experiment with TeX to see what `\string` does when it is followed by an active character like `~`. (Active characters behave like control sequences, but they are not prefixed by an escape.)

> (Page 47) **Exercise 8.2** (d) Are spaces ignored after active characters?

> (Page 155) A `\mathcode` can also have the special value `"8000`, which causes the character to behave as if it has catcode 13 (active). Appendix B uses this feature to make `'` expand to `^{\prime}` in a slightly tricky way.

> (Page 241) For example, ‘`??0.2010`’ and ‘`297.1???`’ have the same width, so their decimal points will line up easily. Here is one way to set up ‘`?`’ for this purpose:
>
> ```
> \newdimen\digitwidth
> \setbox0=\hbox{\rm0}
> \digitwidth=\wd0
> \catcode‘?=\active
> \def?{\kern\digitwidth}
> ```

> (Page 307) **Solution of exercise 7.3** 7.3. 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13. Active characters (type 13) are somewhat special; they behave like control sequences in most cases (e.g., when you say ‘`\let\x=~`’ or ‘`\ifx\x~`’), but they behave like character tokens when they appear in the token list of `\uppercase` or `\lowercase`, and when unexpanded after `\if` or `\ifcat`.

Your question is about the text on page 209, but I mentioned the other parts because they shed light on the matter.

First of all, you see from `\def?{\kern\digitwidth}` that an active character can follow `\def` or `\let` as implicitly told on page 40 and confirmed by the other examples.

Note that saying

```
\catcode`?=\active
\catcode`?=13
\catcode`\?=\active
\catcode`\?=13
```

are all equivalent methods in order to assign category code 13 to the `?` character, because of `\chardef\active=13` that's done both in plain TeX and LaTeX.

The next thing to note is that `\ifcat` compares the category code of the two tokens that follow it *after macro expansion*. So with

```
\catcode`[=13
\def[{*}
\ifcat[*
```

will return **true**, because `[` *is* a macro and its expansion is `*`. To the contrary,

```
\ifcat\noexpand[*
```

will return **false**, because `\noexpand`’s expansion consists in making the next token unexpandable (the first time it is reexamined), so TeX compares two tokens, one of category code 13 and the other of category code 12: the example of page 307 is the one relevant for this application.

Let's see some more examples where I assume

```
\catcode`[=13 \catcode`]=13
```

**First example**

```
\def[{*}\def]{*}
\ifcat[]
```

will return **true**, but not because the characters `[` and `]` are active.

**Second example**

```
\def[{*}\def]{a}
\ifcat[]
```

will return **false**.

**Third example**

```
\def[{*}\def]{a}
\ifcat\noexpand[\noexpand]
```

will return **true**.

---

As an appendix, I add some words on the perhaps cryptic passage about `\uppercase` and `\lowercase`. The main application is something like

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`? \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{whatever}
```

which works and assigns a meaning to the active character `?` (without ever making it active), because `\lowercase` will return `\endgroup\def?` but with `?` having category code 13, because `\uppercase` and `\lowercase` never change category codes, only character codes.

Answer (score 3):

Using the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\catcode`[=13
\catcode`]=13
\def[{*}

\begin{document}

\ifcat\noexpand[\noexpand]
true
\else
false
\fi

\ifcat\noexpand[*
true
\else
false
\fi

\end{document}
```

I get `true` and `false` (in that order) in the resulting document (compiled with pdflatex), and don't get any `Undefined control sequence` errors.

As for question 2, the character `[` is defined to be active (catcode 13), and so is a valid target for a `\def`, as in `\def[{anything goes here}`, and will result in the replacement text being inserted when you type `[` in your document (unless covered by a `\noexpand`)

Further thoughts: `\noexpand` in those conditions stops the expansion, so the first test is comparing the catcodes of `[` and `]` (which are both 13). The second in mine (third in yours) compares `[` to `*` (one is active, the other isn't). The second in yours (not in mine) compares the expansion of `[` (which is `*`) to `*`, and so is true.

Comment: All true but as this is a question about primitives, I'd be minded to use plain for the demo

Comment: Is active character a special control sequence?

Comment: @JosephWright I'm more comfortable in latex rather than tex, but I do understand your point. I don't think what I have significantly changes between the two, but am happy to be wrong.

Comment: @Stephen as I understand it, active characters can be used as control sequences.